# Change flex direction on wrap

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I am trying to use a nested flexbox layout in order to achieve the following layout when there is a certain amount of space:

[image: Example]

Then, when there isn't enough space, the right-hand side should wrap to a *row* layout instead of a *column* layout, so that the boxes are side-by-side when they wrap, example:

[image: Small Layout]

The idea is to have the boxes on the right 50% of the left content so that when they wrap underneath, they are the same combined size as the left content.

However, I can't figure out how to do this via flexbox only. This is what I have so far, but if you resize the window you'll see that the boxes stay in the same direction:

http://jsfiddle.net/usLxshro/

```
div {
    min-height: 50px;
    background: #E7E7E7;
    margin: 10px;
}
#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#left-content {
    flex: 2;
    min-width: 200px;
}
#right-content {
    flex: 1;
    min-width: 200px;
}
section {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: simple float would do it no? http://jsfiddle.net/f5kzn36d/

Comment: @oserk Solves the left/right issue, but does float give me dynamic widths? Would I need to explicitly state the width of the left/right box?

Comment: If you want to use flexbox, would media queries be a viable option? http://jsfiddle.net/dh024mLz/1/

Comment: Why are you posting that as a comment @HiddenHobbes ? Just post it as an answer

Comment: @HiddenHobbes Looks good to me. I can make some assumptions about the screen size to accommodate this.

Comment: @AndreaLigios I suppose I should have, I just wanted clarification from RGraham if this was a suitable solution for their circumstances before I posted a fleshed out answer. Looks like Dmitry had the same idea anyway.

Comment: I've had it too, but you posted it first, so... I'll upvote it if you'll post, and I imagine your will be the accepted one because of the precedence... you decide

Comment: @AndreaLigios No worries, I'll take a loss on this one and give my vote to Dmitry. Apologies if I stopped you from answering, I guess I'm a bit too cautious and don't want to post an answer if there is a chance it isn't suitable.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes you are *way* too polite for a monday morning! :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use media-queries to change behavior

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    #wrapper {
        flex-direction: column;    
    }
    #right-content {
        display: flex;
    }

    section {
        flex: 1;   
    }
}
```

See updated fiddle — http://jsfiddle.net/shurshilin/usLxshro/1/

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: Make sure the `@media` query comes AFTER the initial definition. If you define `#wrapper` further down in your css file than the media query is written it will override it.